# slf4j.Logger not being imported to jHipster project

Tags: logging, gradle, import, jhipster

I am working on this project which is almost done. I added a new Rest Controller for a functionality and I am trying to debug, but I get the following error:

> error: cannot find symbol log.debug

I am importing:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

and on the gradle project,the slf4j is being imported. The log works on another classes but not the one I just added.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you add a bit more information so someone else can reproduce the issue? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to declare a `log` variable.  This is usually done at the top of a class and looks like:

```
public class SampleClassName {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleClassName.class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that.